# I want to quiz myself when I log in

Tags: windows-vista, login

I'd like it so that when I log into my Windows (Vista) user account, I'm forced to answer German vocabulary flash cards. Once the flash cards are answered, I can then return to the desktop as normal. Does anyone know a program with this (or a similar) feature?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any off the top of my head, but if you're into programming, you could write a pretty simple program that takes control of the screen and won't allow you to click off until you've answered the question.

I realize I've essentially told you to write the program you said you're looking for, but if you do enjoy programming, or have thought about giving it a try, this would make a good project. And you'd be improving your German. Two birds with one stone!

Comment: Haha yeah, after posting I started thinking, well gee this seems like a nice do-able project. I might end up doing it.